# VBA message box - how to show a data as a simple table

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

could someone help with that?
How I can show desired data instead of ActiveSheet.. range(...) etc.
the same data to appears in single msgbox?

```
 For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("ecl-table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
    
    With ActiveSheet

    .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent

    .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent

    .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent

     
   End With
```

It would be better if it appears like a simple table.

Comment: "like a simple table" is at least strange for a msgBox. Please, try the next way: `Dim strMsg As string` then `For i = 0 To 2`  `strMsg =strMsg & htmlEle.Children(i).textContent & vbCrLf` `Next i`. Then `MsgBox strMsg`.

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: @FaneDuru you are my luck today :D ok this works but there appears 3 messages,  as in first message is included the data from 1st Children table, in message 2 is included data from message 1 + data from 2nd chlidren table and in message 3 is insuded the data from message 2 + the date from 3rd childaten table. is it possible to appears only last message?

Comment: @QHarr in that particular case it is https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/ecs/ecs_home.jsp?Lang=en&buttonId=&MRN=21PL351020E1091886&Expand=true

Comment: I am afraid that a piece of code from a comment cannot be well understood... `MsgBox strMsg` must be placed **after** `Next i`.

Comment: @FaneDuru it is exactly how I placed it
Dim strMsg As String
        For i = 0 To 2
        strMsg = strMsg & htmlEle.Children(i).textContent & vbCrLf
        Next i
        MsgBox strMsg

Comment: @FaneDuru maybe somehow must get data only from last Child elemnt?

Comment: This is not possible, I'm afraid... In the loop the string is built and **existing only a single MsgBox**, a single message must appear. Are you sure that you did not place another `MsgBox` inside the loop?

Comment: Try running the code line by line, pressing `F8` and see what it does...

Comment: @FaneDuru maybe because it is for "For Each htmlEle In ieObj...."
after "MsgBox strMsg"  it goes to "Next htmlEle"

Comment: Of course, you should place the MsgBox after `End With`...

Comment: @FaneDuru haha :) ok now it appears only one messgare :) thanks